# How to open a PDF file in a Flutter App and have a selectable view?

Tags: flutter, pdf

I want to implement a App in Flutter that allows the user to view PDF-files and select and copy the text thereinin so that I can proceed using the copied text from the Clipboard.

To be more precise I want want my Code to be somewhat like the following but with a package that allows to copy from the displayed PDF file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:pdf_viewer_plugin/pdf_viewer_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class PDFPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final File file;
  final Function onPressed;
  const PDFPage(this.file,this.onPressed);
  @override
  _PDFPageState createState() => _PDFPageState();
}

class _PDFPageState extends State<PDFPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: ''));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PdfViewer(
        filePath: widget.file.path,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.beach_access),
        onPressed: ()async{
          ClipboardData data = await Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
          widget.onPressed(data);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The package I am using here is

```
pdf_viewer_plugin: ^1.0.0+2
```

That seems not to work. It does display the PDF file but I can't select text or copy from it.  I have also tried

```
flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6
advance_pdf_viewer: ^1.1.6
```

and some more I can't remind the name of.

Is there a package that allows me to do so, or a modest way to either modify or create such a package?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use dio package for download the file and open_file package to open the downloaded file

Comment: But wouldn't that open the file in another App and my FloatingActionButton is no longer displayed?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution maybe?

Comment: @PawełZgoda-Ferchmin No, I haven't found a solution yet. The best thing I could do by now was transformig the *.pdf into a String via [link](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_text) and then use SelectableText. But that is not a good solution as the transformation of *.pdf to String takes a very significant amount of time and I loose all of the good looking features of a *.pdf. I guess one has to write a whole new package for such a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing the package that you're using, [syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer) has support for selecting and copying text from the opened PDF.